# more efficient filter of progress 4gl trace logs in logstash

Tags: logging, filter, logstash, openedge, grok

I have successfully filtered my logs but curious if I can make it more efficient or "better" way rather than using a ton of "NOTSPACE". Below is my sample logs as well as my grok filter.

****Updated with more recent version******

```
[15/09/28@09:40:23.467-0700] P-000685 T-956770080 2 WS 4GLTRACE       Run shr/getpref.p " Traveler ID Format" [Main Block - docprep/frames.w @ 1016]
```

My grok filter:

```
%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{MONTHDAY}@%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}-%{INT:TIMEZONE}%{NOTSPACE:BRACKET}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:PID}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:T}%{SPACE}%{INT:NUM}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:WS}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:4GLTRACE}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:STATUS}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:MAINPROGRAM}%{GREEDYDATA:SUBPROGRAM}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:BRACKET}
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use brackets in your pattern, though you have to escape the opening one, so:

```
\[ .... ]
```

could be used around your date/time.

Also, you can use %{TIME} instead of the three individual patterns.

Several of your %{NOTSPACE} could be %{WORD} which might make more sense in a few months when you revisit the grok{}.  %{WORD} is \b\w+\b, which would include alphanumeric characters and the underscore.

You can use a literal space in your pattern when you know there will be only one:

```
%{WORD} %{WORD}
```

which will also boost readability.

I also try to reserve GREEDYDATA for "extra stuff at the end".  Check out %{QS} for quoted strings.